# What are the rules (or traditions) to deal with an answer when there is an earlier comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, attribution

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498702/what-is-the-type-of-http-get-to-use-as-a-parameter-in-a-function) where I laid out my approach to a problem. A comment mentioned that there is a better way, which is true (lack of experience in Go → convoluted solution).

I was about to say "thanks, could you please turn that comment into an answer" (or maybe delete the question as the comment, though very much correct, completely destroyed the question).

An answer popped up, with essentially the content of the comment.

What is the *blessed* way to go further (after having left some time for maybe even better answers)?

- accept the answer?
- ask the commenter to write an answer with his comment and accept that one?

Comment: You can still ask the commenter if they want to write an answer. In any case, the existing answer should have cited their source(s). Their code appears to be from the documentation.

Comment: There is a third option: write an answer yourself. You can give credit to the commenter in the post by mentioning their name (and linking to their profile).

Comment: @VLAZ: I am not a big fan of that because the rep goes to the wrong person (I do not care at all about mine, but there are people who do). I usually suggest in that case to the commenter to just bootstrap an answer (even with the content of the comment) and I would then work on it to format, add links, etc. It worked I think once (= an answer stub was created). But yes, this is a good third solution.

Comment: @WoJ you can mark your answer as a community wiki and you won't get rep from it.

Comment: @VLAZ: that's right - but it is less me not wanting to get the rep (I do not care) but me wanting the rep to go to the person who actually helped me. I am also kind of a back seat editor: I like to reformat for readability, add links to docs,  and so on - because some people are just good at giving the right answer without necessarily having a neat way to convey the info. I learned a lot about that when teaching (students, then helping my children to write stuff that is understandable to others).

Comment: @WoJ - you can give them a bounty on another post if you really want to say thanks (but choose a worthy post as well). As others already mentioned - just ping them otherwise, if they want to, they will come back and convert to a proper answer. You can't force somebody to accept gratitude :)

Comment: @WoJ - If the author wanted reputation they wouldn’t have submitted a solution as a comment.

Comment: @SecurityHound I will often leave a comment if 1) it's really short, and 2) I'm not 100% sure it will solve the asker's problem.  Sometimes I do it just in the hopes that someone else can flesh it out into a worthy answer, and I'll come back in a day or two and leave a vote if they did.  It's all about helping people out.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Right;  I do the exact same thing, but I don't care about the reputation, so somebody shouldn't feel bad submitting an actual answer.

Comment: @OlegValter NO Do not use bounties to reward a person! Rewarding bounties are to reward posts and posts only. By offering a bounty to a post you send a strong signal that this post helped you a lot, if you do so because of a completely unrelated event, future readers will have the wrong message.

Comment: @Kaiido - I think I know what I said :) "choose a worthy post" is there for a reason.

Comment: @OlegValter that's still a NO. The fact you are rewarding this other post is still because of an unrelated event, you are still using the bounty system to reward someone, you should simply not do that.

Answer (score 36):

If someone wanted to write an answer they would have done so.

Leaving a comment is often done when either the question or providing an answer isn't seen as useful. Or they are unsure they got the problem right. Nothing wrong with that.

In your case, someone else provided a proper answer. Accept it. If the commenter later circles back and upgrade their comment into a (better) answer you can consider switching your accept vote. If there are quality issues with the answer (missing attribution, low quality, etc) that can't be fixed with an edit, do cast a downvote. I guess it is uncommon to accept an answer and also downvote it but the system won't block that.

If your question was left without an answer it would have been early enough to pressure the commenter in upgrading their comment to an answer.

Note that some tags are slightly differently moderated than others. It might be that tag followers don't fancy answers to trivial questions. If answers pop up anyway they might be downvoted. That can be a reason experts leave a comment at best but don't bother with an answer.

Comment: Once a question has an accepted answer, it's much less likely that someone will write another answer - they'll see it as a worthless exercise, unless that accepted answer is lacking in some crucial way.

Comment: It takes a lot more work to write a good answer than to offer a helpful comment. Helping the person is its own reward for me.   If I'm commenting it's because I don't want to put forth the effort it would take to earn rep from an answer.

Comment: Writing a comment also attracts no risk, which I think might be why some people answer trivial questions in this sort of way. Ie, some people will downvote the question and answers when they think a question should have been closed instead of answered. A comment means you can be helpful - but also lazy.

Comment: Just a minor thing: missing attribution can be fixed with an edit.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, if the answer answers your question, **you should accept the answer**, given that the answerer included proper attribution to the user who commented *(if the context of the answer is the exact same as the comment*).

Always remember: **Comments are temporary**, and even ones that answer a question won't guarantee to remain long enough for people who encounter the same problem in the future to see.

When **no** attribution is provided, you might also want to consider how the answerer might not have seen the comment, have been working on their answer before the comment, etc., meaning that **they probably answered completely on their own**.

---

*P.S.*

I often find myself working on a proper answer, and another user comments the answer *(without the quality of what an answer-in-post should have, hence faster)*. It shouldn't, but it kind of makes me feel like I need to include a *"Like perfectly pointed out by..."* at the start of my answer...

Just a few days ago, a user called me "rep mining" for answering a question that had a "comment answer". Honestly, I didn't even see the comment when I posted.

Another time, after leaving a time gap in case the commenter decides to answer using the answer box, I transferred a comment into an answer box and provided proper attribution. But another user downvoted and said my answer belonged to the user who commented. Still, the OP later thanked me *(and upvoted)* for posting the answer, addressing that I provided proper attribution and didn't see why it got downvoted.

Comment: personally i'd prefer people *not* put my name in their answers

Comment: I thought rep was farmed, not mined.

Answer (score -1):

I have reasons for commenting instead of answering, and actually also have reasons for answering instead of commenting. Let me explain the latter scenario first.

Markdown code works best as an answer. I'm not talking about markdown describing an object, class, or something else - I'm talking about 5+ lines of code that need to be formatted to be understood. When I think it might help answer an issue, I may comment first but will note in my answer why I'm doing this. If it's not helpful? I find it easy to delete the answer... no harm, no foul.

It's the former that is mostly.... instinct for me. If I *know* I can post an answer, of course, do it. (Well unless there's already an answer!) But many times I can only infer one of a few things. Do I really understand the issue? Is my answer really helpful or wanted? Do *I* need clarification from the OP? At some point I may even wonder if the OP knows what the actual issue is! These are reasons for commenting, not answering IMHO.

And what matters to me is getting at the actual issue and resolving it. A clear, well-worded question with a clear answer gets an upvote from me - regardless of if someone "beat me to it". (And I'm learning to upvote clear and well-worded questions too.)